# How is routing with nested modules supposed to work in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I can't for the love of cookies figure out how to configure the most recent incarnation of the Angular 2 router (the one from the final release). I have a rather large Angular 2 RC5 app up and running, but need to migrate to the final release now before I can move on.

In this app I have a lot of nested components that, according to Google's docs, should be organised as features in module. The typical URL in my app looks like so

```
user/34/section/95/client/13/<feature>
```

but there are also a few others, such as

```
user/34/settings
```

so in this case, `settings` would be a feature module.

I've read the docs, which are rather long-winded and are in no hurry to cut to the chase, only to find out that this case isn't covered at all. I can't believe that this scenario isn't going to work, it would seem to be a huge oversight so I suppose the problem is that I haven't quite grasped how this router actually works - and I have a feeling that I'm not the only one.

I've created [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0yL3m32TnPE9xccDohZC?p=preview) to illustrate my point.

In this plunker I got 2 levels of nesting

```
app -> benutzer (user) -> klient (client)
```

just enough to make the issue appear. The expected outcome is that I can navigate to

```
benutzer/78/klient/56
```

i.e. the router actually *finds* that route, which at the moment it doesn't.

Before I moved the code to plunker and added `dashboard.component` (because I can't easily modify the URL in plunker, so I have to resort to `routerLink`) I could actually navigate to

```
klient/56
```

which shouldn't be possible. It seems that each route defined in another module is added to the root instead of building on top of each other.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at all your routes.

```
appRoutes = [      // AppModule
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashaboard' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent
];
benutzerRoutes = [ // BenutzerModule
  { path: 'benutzer/:id', component BenutzerComponent }
];
klientRoutes = [   // KlinetModule
  { path: 'klient/:id', component: KlientComponent }
]
```

The way you import your modules doesn't have any effect on how the routes are constructed. How they are constructed are simply based on how we construct the. What you are expecting with this

```
AppModule
   imports -> BenutzerModule
                   imports -> KlinetModule
```

leading to the following routes

```
dashboard/benutzer/:id/klient/:id
```

is just not the case. Each one of those route arrays are simply added to the root. That's why you can access `klient/:id` and not `dashboard/benutzer/:id`.

I've read the complete documentation for routing a few times, and there aren't any example of nested routes in different modules. All the examples had modules that were loaded from the root route, as your example does, or having nested routes being part of the same route configuration. So since there are no example I guess we need to just work with what we know and decide for ourselves what's the best way.

There are a couple ways I can think of. The first, most obvious but IMO more intrusive than the next option, is to just add the full routes to the paths

```
appRoutes = [      // AppModule
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashaboard' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent
];
benutzerRoutes = [ // BenutzerModule
  { path: 'dashboard/benutzer/:id', component BenutzerComponent }
];
klientRoutes = [   // KlinetModule
  { path: 'dashboard/benutzer/:id/klient/:id', component: KlientComponent }
]
```

I say this option is more intrusive, as it forces the children to know about the parent. In Angular 2 architecture that is counter to how we structure our components. Parents should know about children, but not necessarily vice versa.

The other option I can think of is to use `loadChildren` to load the child modules lazily. I say "lazily" because I can't figure out how to do this eagerly, and not sure if it is even possible to do so. To load the children lazily, we can do

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/benutzer',
    loadChildren: 'app/benutzer/benutzer.module#BenutzerModule'
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];
export const benutzerRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: BenutzerComponent },
  {
    path: ':id/klient',
    loadChildren: 'app/klienten/klienten.module#KlientenModule'
  }
];
export const klientenRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: KlientComponent }
];
```

In this case we would remove the all the child module imports from their parent `@NgModule`. This allows for lazy loading of the module. If we leave then, then the module will be loaded eagerly on startup, but not have the desired effect (hence why I said I am not how to do this eagerly).

Also notice the `loadChildren`. In the above example I use `app` as the root. The only reason is that I tested in local environment. I am not a big fan of Plunker. For your Plunker though, you should use `src` as the root.

IMO, the lazy loading *looks* cleaner, as child doesn't know about parent, but this *forces* you to lazily load the modules, which may not be desired. In some cases though, it is desired, as it allows for a lighter initial load.

For more on lazy loading, see the docs routing section on [Asynchronous Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-6-asynchronous-routing)

Comment: Indeed, there's lots of documentation and this real world scenario isn't dealt with at all. Actually, they hint at nested modules/routes but they never come up with an example, so my guess is they simply skipped this feature for final.

Comment: Marked as answer because of the alternative solution using lazy loading, which is what I settled for in the end.

Comment: I picked the second solution too, but it's freak me out, that such a simple thing have not been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution, copying my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39629949/370935

I got this to work as well and unless you actually need to render all parent components in the hierarchy I think my solution is far more elegant.

The key to understanding my approach is that all routes, no matter how deeply nested in modules are added to the root module. Quick example, let's say we have a `DepartmentModule` and an `EmployeeModule` which we'd like to navigate to using this URL

```
/department/1/employee/2
```

at which point we'd see employee 2's details. Configuring routes for `department` in `department.routing.ts` and `employee` in `employee.routing.ts` will *not* work the way we intended and you'll notice that you can navigate to

```
/employee/2
```

from the root component, while

```
/department/1/employee/2
```

will crash (route not found). A typical route configuration in this scenario would look like this:

```
export const departmentRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'department', component: DepartmentComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: DepartmentsComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: DepartmentDetailsComponent }
    ]}
];

export const employeeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'employee', component: EmployeeComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: EmployeesComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: EmployeeDetailsComponent }
    ]}
];
```

and `EmployeeModule` would be imported by `DepartmentModule`. Now, like I said, that doesn't work unfortunately.

However, with just a single change it will:

```
export const employeeRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'department/:id/employee', component: EmployeeComponent, children: [
        { path: '', component: EmployeesComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: EmployeeDetailsComponent }
    ]}
];
```

The catch is, that `DepartmentModule` is not taking an active part anymore as soon you navigate to an `employee` URL, but you still can access every parameter from the `ActivatedRoute`:

```
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent {
    departmentId: number;
    employeeId: number;
    constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
        route.parent.params.subscribe(params =>
            this.departmentId= +params['id'])
        route.params.subscribe(params => 
            this.employeeId= +params['id']);
    }
}
```

I wonder if this is supposed to be the official approach, but for now this works for me until the next breaking change from the Angular 2 team .

Comment: I was just testing and writing up [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39630242/2587435) when you posted yours :-) The first part of my answer provides a solution pretty much the same as yours, but offers a second solution of lazy loading. Check it out.