# Angular2 Define child routes from sub-routing module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

First of all, I've seen this post which seems to be close to my issue but I admit I got kind of lost : [How to route to a Module as a child of a Module - Angular 2 RC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879529/how-to-route-to-a-module-as-a-child-of-a-module-angular-2-rc-5)

I'll try to make it simple :

- I have my `app.component.html` file which has a `<router-outlet>`.
- In this first outlet, my `MasterModule` loads the `MasterComponent` which has another `<router-outlet>`. From my `MasterRoutingModule`, I can then define my child routes from my `MasterComponent`.
- I have my other module (`EquipmentSLModule`), which has his own routes, and my aim is to add child routes (to be loaded inside my second `<router-outlet>` from `MasterComponent`) from my `EquipmentSLRouting`.

Is there a way to do that ?

N.B : I know there is no code yet, I'll edit and add some in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render your loaded module under a component `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` hood you need to config as children's of particular component. 
I made a quick example for what you need, check out here is the link [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WeGDsP0czhMVRXyW7Bf5?p=preview)

```
  imports: [BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([{
              path: '',
              pathMatch: 'full',
              redirectTo: '/home'
          },
          {
              path: 'home',
              component: AppHome
              children: [{
                  path: 'ModuleA',
                  loadChildren: 'src/ModuleA'
              }]
          },
      ])
  ]
```

Comment: @alex-beugnet is it what your thinking or it's different?

Comment: Yes, this seems pretty good, as the other answers ! The plunkr really helped. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do I need to go through lazy loaded modules only ?

Comment: or else you can import the module as a regular import.

Comment: I mean, in your plunkr you define the child route as follow : `children: [{path: 'ModuleA', loadChildren: 'src/ModuleA'}`

Can I just define some child routes from the `app.ts` and some other child routes from the `ModuleA.ts` ?

Comment: yes you can add.`children: [{path: 'ModuleA', loadChildren: 'src/ModuleA'},{path: 'home2',  component: AppHome2}]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand what your asking.  Each Module can have it's own routing.  You can then reference that routing as children of a path like this:

In your AppRouting, load the routes from the :

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'masterRoute',
        loadChildren: './path/to/MasterRoutingModule.module#MasterRoutingModule' }
    }
]
```

In your MasterRouting, load the EquipmentSLModule's routes as well to utilize the `<router-outlet>` in the root component of the MasterModule:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: MasterComponent }, //root
    {
        path: 'otherRoute',
        loadChildren: './path/to/EquipmentSLModule.module#EquipmentSLModule' }
    }
]
```

This will load routes from the `EquipmentSLModule` as routes in the MastRoutingModule.

In your `EquipmentSLModule` you will import the routes for that module with `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`, same for the MasterModule.  The AppModule will use `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this :

```
   //... 
   const EquipmentSLRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'equipment-sl',  component: EquipmentSLComponent },
      { path: 'equipment-sl/:id', component: EquipmentSLDetailComponent }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        //...
        RouterModule.forChild(EquipmentSLRoutes)
      ],
      exports: [
        //...
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
    export class EquipmentSLModule { }
```

add this module to your `MasterModule` imports array.